# How does the sorting of ArrayList of custom object works?

Tags: java, sorting, object, arraylist

How does this list.sort() method is actually sorting the objects according to their property.
This is a solution for a LeetCode question 1337.

```
class Solution {
public int[] kWeakestRows(int[][] mat, int k) {
    List<Pair> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i = 0; i < mat.length; i++) {
        int cur = 0;
        for(int j = 0; j < mat[0].length; j++) {
            cur += mat[i][j];
        }
        Pair p = new Pair();
        p.index = i;
        p.count = cur;
        list.add(p);
    }

    list.sort((lh, rh) -> 
        lh.count != rh.count ? lh.count - rh.count : lh.index - rh.index
    );

    int[] ret = new int[k];
    for(int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        ret[i] = list.get(i).index;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

}

```
class Pair {
int index;
int count;
}
```

Comment: First add `getIndex()` and `getCount()` to `Pair`, then your current code could be replaced with `list.sort(Comparator.comparing(Pair::getCount).thenComparing(Pair::getIndex));` which does the same thing but is far more readable. And I hope is so much more readable that you can understand it. The original version is not my idea of good code.

Comment: What is the question, how do sort algorithms work?

Answer (score 0):

`List.sort` takes a `Comparator` in argument. 
 As `Pair` does not implement `Comparable` you can not use natural ordering. So here the comparator is substituted with a lambda and this implementation uses the `count` and `index` properties to apply ordering.

Comment: Probably you meant `Pair`, not `Point`.

Comment: Yes.Thank you ;-)

Comment: so basically we have used lambda expression to implement Comparator in short?

Comment: `Comparator` is a functional interface and you can substitute any functional interface with a lambda in java. Func interface = interface with only one abstract method.